# Why aren't PHP short tags working when they are enabled?

Tags: php, ubuntu

Weird problem with PHP setup on ubuntu. I enabled short tags in php.ini, which is loaded and php info says short tags are enabled as well.

```
/# php -v
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 (cli) ( NTS )

/# php --ini | grep php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/php.ini

/# grep short /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/php.ini
short_open_tag = On

/# php -i | grep short
short_open_tag => On => On
```

Nevertheless, `<?` is not interpreted as PHP and is just printed out in browser. If I change `<?` to `<?php`, everything works.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might also want to ask askUbuntu

Comment: Are you running the code which doesn't work in the console or a browser.

Comment: `/etc/php/7.0/cli/*` does not affect configuration of PHP loaded by webserver.

Comment: @NigelRen doesn't work in browser, works in console !

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` in the browser and see what the correct ini file is.

Comment: Ahh, I see where the problem is ... thanks guys, will try

Comment: Note that using the short tag `<?`  is a bad practice (in particular it causes problems with xml declarations).

Comment: Indeed, I thought cli and apache use the same php.ini. Now everything works, thanks for support